# asp net mvc change model within if condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I know we can only have one model in a view. But I want to get it within a condition.

```
  @if (ViewBag.type == "multiple")
  {
      @model IEnumerable<Student>
  }
  else if (ViewBag.type == "single")
  {
      @model Student
  }
```

But It gives me error. " Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file."

Thanks for help.

Comment: You cant. Create 2 views, or if you need 1 view, use a view model with properties for each, or use `@Html.Action()` to call a method that returns partial views of one or both

Comment: Why can't you have always `@model IEnumerable<Student>` and in case of single mode just with one element inside?

Comment: If you show more details maby the best solution for you will be using Editor or Display template

Comment: This logic should be in the Controller...I also agree with @StephenMuecke...just create 2 views, it's easier to manage/handle as it grows.

Comment: This is not the recommended approach or it's wrong design. It will be better if you provide more details what exactly is needed.

Comment: when you have two type of model your cshtml logic should change and you need to create to view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `IEnumerable<Student>` in both cases.

If `ViewBag.type == "single"` then use

`@Model.FirstOrDefault()` to get the single student value out.

You cannot define 2 different types of Model unless you go with `Dynamic` type model